# How do I create a loop in omnet++?

Tags: c++, network-programming, omnet++

How do I create a loop in omnet ++ with a user defined variable.
I tried the following but it gave me an error:
network Network{

```
  parameters:

        int n @prompt("enter number") = default(2);

    connections:

        for i=0..n do { // here the n gives me a syntax error (unexpected NAME, expected { 
            //do things

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [OMNeT++ manual](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/usman.html#sec130). The `for` syntax is without `do`, e.g.

```
for i = 0..count-2 {
        node[i].port[1] <--> node[i+1].port[0];
}
```